# Crash on QwtPlotZoomer in QT5

Tags: qt, qt5, qwt

I am trying to use a `QwtPlotZoomer` in QT5, but I get a seg fault when its constructor runs.

```
class Qwt_widget : public QwtPlot
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Qwt_widget(QWidget* parent = 0) :
    QwtPlot(parent),
    m_canvas()
  {
    QwtPlotZoomer zoomer(&m_canvas); // Crashes here
  }

private:
  QwtPlotCanvas m_canvas;
};
```

The above widget is added to a simple main window so that it will be created (full code at https://github.com/chrisburnham/Qwt_qt5_crash). Also here are the QWT lines that I have added to the QT creators default pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qwt
LIBS += -lqwt-qt5
```

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 and installed Qt5 with `libqt5-default` (5.9.5) and QWT with `libqwt-qt5-dev` (6.1.3). I have checked all my libraries with LDD and looked at the headers I am using and they are all coming from the packages that were installed with `libqwt-qt5-dev`. I have previously used `QwtPlotZoomers` in this way in Qt4 (with the Qt4 version of QWT) and as far as I can tell from the documentation it should still work here.

Comment: canvas is a local variable that will be removed when the object that can generate problems is finished, so a possible solution is to make a canvas attribute of the class.

Comment: @eyllanesc I originally had it as a member variable and it results in the same crash. I can change it back if that would help clarify where the crash is coming from.

Comment: I did not say that that was the solution but if a cause of another problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the `QwtPlotCanvas` to the `QwtPlot` before you ask `QwtPlotZoomer` to work on it. Note that [QwtPlot::setCanvas()](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/class_qwt_plot.html#aea67c885034219789b360c0e624bfeaf) takes ownership, so do not use a member variable for the canvas.

But since you are using a default `QwtPlotCanvas` and not some derived class you could probably just use the canvas `QwtPlot` comes with:

```
QwtPlotZoomer zoomer(this->canvas()); // Should not crash here
```